# How do I make a dropdown that also loads content into the mainContent area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I have a dropdown using JQuery on my site (www.hidcountry.com) but I am trying to make it dropdown but at the same time load content into the mainContent section on the right. The pages are PHP but I was told Javascript, Ajax or JQuery will help me do that but I'm so stuck right now... Anybody have an experience with this?

Comment: to clarify, you want the content to change depending on the last menu item they clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you want content to change once someone selects a menu item in the drop-down, I would recommend using the jQuery library and [binding a javascript function to the change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/).  This would then let you code a javascript function that you could use to change content in different areas of the page:

```
$('#my-drop-down').change(function(){ $('#content-area').html('Some HTML.'); });
```